# What is the most pleasant way to signal to a user that no search results were found in android?

Tags: android-search

I have the following problem: 
I use a ListView-Activity and an arrayadapter to display search results. Now, if there are no search results, the Activity consists only of a blank page.

What do you think is the best way to react to such a scenario? Should I implement two fragments, one  with a Button and a Textview and show the proper fragment, according to which search results are given? Or should I just start another Activity from the ListView-Activity?

I am interested in your suggestions.

Greetings, 
Sleik

Answer (score 0):

You can try making a dialog on the screen and then try to finish the dialog and the listview activity when the button is pressed.